# Project Euler #19 code seems right. What am I missing?

Tags: php

**Problem 19:**

> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some
>   research for yourself.
>
> 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
>
> Thirty days has September, April, June and
>   November.
>
> All the rest have thirty-one, Saving February alone, Which
>   has twenty-eight, rain or shine. And on leap years, twenty-nine.
>
> A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a
>   century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> **How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?**

I thought that using PHP for this would be a breeze since it has so many built-in time and date functions. My code is really quite simple, so I'm having a hard time seeing what I'm doing that's wrong.

**My code:**

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $sunday_count = 0;
    for( $year = 1901; $year <= 2000; $year++ ) {
        for( $month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++ ) {
            // Produces a date in format: 1/1/2000
            $date = $month . "/1/" . $year;
            $time = strtotime( $date );
            $is_sunday = ( date( 'l', $time ) == "Sunday" );
            echo "$date "
               . ( $is_sunday ? 'was a Sunday. ' : '' )
               . "<br>";
            if( $is_sunday ) $sunday_count++;
        }
    }
    echo "Answer: $sunday_count";
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The solution my code comes up with is 169, which is not correct. Any idea?

**Edit 1**

The solution is supposed to be 171.

Using Wolfram Alpha and my Windows clock, I've doubled checked several of the Sundays which my code reports. All of them check out OK.

So it seems my code is reporting valid and legitimate Sundays, but somehow it has missed two of them.

**Edit 2**

I made the following minor change to the formatting of the date in my code:

```
$date = sprintf('%d-%02d-01', $year, $month); // formats yyyy-mm-dd
```

I then used @MadaraUchiha's code to generate an array containing the 171 correct dates.

After comparing his dates with mine, these are the two missed dates:

> 1901-09-01
>   1901-12-01

**Edit 3**

[Codepad also shows](http://codepad.org/hHHKqJQ6) that these dates are not Sundays (but they really should be).

And I am certain that the dates are correctly being interpreted as YYYY-MM-DD because one of the dates my code offers to the solution is 2000-10-01, which would only be a Sunday if 10 is the month, not the day.

**Edit 4**

So apparently if on a 32 bit system, Unix timestamps won't work outside of the range:

```
Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT
```

to

```
Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT
```

Comment: It probably is related to this note on [phpdoc](http://php.net/strtotime): "In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given weekday in a month where that weekday was the first day of the month would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp. This has been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions." ?

Comment: I'm running PHP Version 5.3.10 so I suspect it is something else.

Comment: Turns out, this isn't related to php at all. It is the definition of 20th century that caused the confusion. See the discussion on [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/thursday-code-puzzler-all) thread.

But, I wonder how people got 171.

Wikipedia defines the range otherwise. ProjEuler perhaps is using one definition and, different answer.

Comment: @goldenparrot It's not really ambiguous. The original question states the date range: 1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "confusion"?

Comment: I give up. Even counting from 1900 to 2000 is giving 169.

Comment: My solution gives a correct result. Go over it, and see which dates I have that you don't.

Comment: Your code works here: `Answer: 171`. (PHP 5.3.8 (cli))

Comment: Something's borken on [codepad](http://codepad.org/cLIHNwvR).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, codepad and my computer wrongly call those two dates Thursday instead of Sunday. Why?

Comment: @Joncom Emil Vikström answered that: they're using a 32-bit timestamp, so calculating the time stamp for earlier dates overflows and they compute garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it might not work on some systems using timestamps is that the range of a Unix timestamp on 32-bit systems is from `Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT` to `Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT`, so you miss almost all months in the first year.

64-bit systems have larger integers which makes the range bigger (in PHP).

Comment: That seems to cover the two dates. Apache is running 64-bit on my system. Is this what you mean by a 64-bit system?

Comment: Check `PHP_INT_MAX`. It is `9223372036854775807` on my 64-bit system.

Comment: PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647 on my system. I suppose then that is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I get 171 with this (much shorter, and more readable) code, using DateTime objects:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain"); //Browser display

$time = new DateTime("1901-01-01");
$end = new DateTime("2000-12-31");

$counter = 0;

while (!$time->diff($end)->invert) { //$time isn't greater than $end
    $time->modify("+1 month");
    if ($time->format("l") == "Sunday") {
        $counter++;
        echo $time->format("Y-m-d") . " was a Sunday!\n";
    }
}

echo "\nTotal number of Sundays: $counter";
```

When using DateTime objects, you're treating dates as **Dates** and not as **numbers** or **strings**. This gives you a huge flexibility advantage over any other approaches.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Your code works well on my system also. However I'm curious if you might be able to tell me why in my code 2 months appear to be "skipped"? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on this code is the line

`$date = $month . "/1/" . $year;`

this should be

`$date = "1/".$month."/" . $year;`

You mixed the places of months and days.